# Disabling transaction in Rails Migration: How do I include a ruby variable in a block like the following

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, migration, database-migration, postgresql-9.2

```
execute <<-SQL
  commit
  reindex database ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]['database'] 
SQL
```

Obviously that doesn't work but you get the idea. I don't know what the above code structure is even called to go look it up.

Postgres doesn't allow a db reindex inside a transaction, so I'm hoping the above hack will work since there doesn't appear to be a way to disable transactions until Rails 4

```
UPDATE
```

So the above didn't work, but this hack did:

```
# force a reindex after we switched all those columns to citext
execute "commit;"
execute "reindex database #{ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]['database']} force;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<<-SQL` ... `SQL` part creates a multi-line string, which is the argument for the `execute` function. You can include ruby expressiosn in that string, as in the usual `"value #{myObject.value}"` strings. This would make:

```
execute <<-SQL
  commit
  reindex database #{ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]['database']}
SQL
```

I can't tell you if that SQL hack works or not. But it seems like you are closing a running transaction, which is later closed again (by the code, that originally started the transaction). Plus there might be a reason for that transaction. I mean, if rails tries to roll back your transaction later, it will fail (or at least not work), as you've already committed the transaction.

Comment: Thanks a lot Philipp. It's definitely a hack, just trying to get over a hump until Rails 4 hits. They have a call in there called ```disable_ddl_transaction!``` that lets you do what I'm trying to do above.